# show images on the templates of django using google app engine

Tags: python, django, image, google-app-engine

i am using google app engine with django to make a small application that it has these features

1. upload images ,
2. show images ,
3. minipulate images (rotate)

well after finishing part 1 , now i am somewhere stuck in part 2 where i need to show images.
i did everything i retrieved the image keys, but the images are not showing.
only the titles of the images i saved in the datastore.

here is my code:

```
    <ul>
        {% for image in image.all %}
            <li>{{ image.title }}   </li>
            <li> <img  src="/pictures/models.{{image.key}}"/>   </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

Comment: How did you upload them? How were they saved? How are you serving those images? What is in your app.yaml for the picture URL?

Comment: Are you using blobstore or just a blob property to save your images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming

- You uploaded the images to the blobstore
- image.key is the blobstore key
- You have a handler named BlobstoreImageHandler for `/pictures/models\.(.*)/`

Then you'd do something like

```
class BlobstoreImageHandler(blobstore.handler.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
  def get(self, resource):
    resourse = str(urllib.unquote(resource))
    blob_info = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(resource)
    self.send_blob(blob_info)
```

which is straight out of http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview.html#Serving_a_Blob

Comment: yes but i am using different django version and also app engine helper as the doctor wants us and i think they are not compatable with the situation , bug accured , i spend 7 hours trying to work it out using the docs , but no. thanks