# Dynamically loading BlobProperty images on Appengine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

First, I'm extremely new to coding and self-taught, so models / views / DOM fall on deaf ears (but willing to learn!)

So I saved images into a database as blobs (BlobProperty), now trying to serve them.

**Relevant Code:** (I took out a ton for ease of reading)

```
class Mentors(db.Model):
    id = db.StringProperty()
    mentor_id = db.StringProperty()
    name = db.StringProperty()
    img_file = db.BlobProperty()
```

```
class ImageHandler (webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):

    mentor_id=self.request.get('mentor_id')
    mentor = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Mentors WHERE mentor_id = :1 LIMIT 1", mentor_id)
    if mentor.img_file:
       self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = "image/jpg"
       self.response.out.write(mentor.img_file)
    else:
       self.error(404)
```

```
application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    routes.DomainRoute('medhack.prebacked.com', medhack_pages),
    webapp2.Route(r'/', handler=HomepageHandler, name='home-main'),
    webapp2.Route(r'/imageit', handler=ImageHandler, name='image-handler')
    ],
        debug=True)
```

```
class MedHackHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, url="/"):
        # ... bunch of code to serve template etc.

        mentors_events = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Mentors_Events WHERE event_id = :1 ORDER BY mentor_type DESC, mentor_id ASC", current_event_id)
        mentors = mentors_events
```

html:

```
{% for m in mentors %}
        #here 'mentors' refers to mentors_event query, and 'mentor' refers to the mentors table above.
        <img src="imageit?mentor_id={{m.mentor.mentor_id}}" alt="{{m.mentor.name}} headshot"/>
{% endfor %}
```

Its seems that imageit isn't actually being called or the path is wrong or... I don't know.  So many attempts and fails.

Resources I've tried but fail to understand:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/python/serving_dynamic_images
[show images on the templates of django using google app engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284413/show-images-on-the-templates-of-django-using-google-app-engine)
https://sites.google.com/site/usfcomputerscience/storing-and-serving-images

This seemed to be dang close, but I can't figure out how to implement. Need a "for dummies" translation.
[How to load Blobproperty image in Google App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283001/how-to-load-blobproperty-image-in-google-app-engine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the handler, you're getting the ID from `self.request.get('mentor_id')`. However, in the template you've set the image URL to `imageit?key=whatever` - so the parameter is "key" not "mentor_id". Choose one or the other.

Comment: Good catch, thanks. Fixed, but still no dice. Updated it in the code.

Comment: Choosing this as the answer as I didn't give enough information (subdomain routing was wrong) and you caught another of my errors.  Thanks Daniel.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out.

I'm using a subdomain, and wasn't setting up *that* route, only /img coming off of the www root.

I also wasn't using the URL correctly and the 15th pass of https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/python/serving_dynamic_images finally answered my problem.